# apache, localhost not working in windows 7

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, host

i'm having trouble accessing my localhost: it wont seem to load!
chrome says "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost" and then some suggestions and firefox gives a timeout error. As if they are looking for localhost over the internet.
i have also tried 127.0.0.1 with the same result.
I have Apache installed and earlier i would get a 404 error. **i got rid of that** by disabling SQL reporting services (i have MS SQL installed aswell).
If i do "Wamp icon>>Apache>>Services>>Test port 80" it says:

> "Your port 80 is not actually used"

i have also made sure that

> 127.0.0.1             localhost

is in the "host" file.

I have been trying to figure out the problem since the past 3 days but havnt been able to find an answer.

I would appreciate if anyone can help.
Thank you.

OS: Windows 7 ultimate x64

Comment: Try, at the command prompt, `telnet localhost 80`: do you get a connection?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue in my windows 7 home basic.

Maybe you could solve by this:

1)Your port 80 is mostly blocked by Microsoft iis server. so if iis is using port 80 than apache wont be able to use the port.

2) So, change the listening port of apache. apache has a file name httpd.conf.Open the file in a text editor and there will be port 80 already written, change the port to 8080 (mostly people use 8080).

3)So now your Apache runs on different port.

4) Restart apache services or restart your wamp server.

5)now Open your local host by, `http://localhost:8080`

6)you will see your localhost page.

Hope it solved your problem.

Comment: Hm, after upgrading Debian Wheezy to Jessie, port 80 is not working to. Changing the port fixed that, but what is wrong with an old port?...

Comment: It seems like, I found it...see /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
There is path to /var/www/html, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Skype running, close it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to not given the access on your firewall to apache.

Do the following step:

- left click on Wamp tray icon.
- Click on Apache folder
- Then go to Service Then Click on install service.
- then a command prompt will open and ask you to click any key to
  continue.
- Press any key and then a firewall popup will open, give access to
  them.

enjoy.

Comment: kya baat !! mast tabish bhai !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your windows folder from C:,
navigate to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
look for Host (Note: because this is windows 7, u won't be aalows to modify the host file=====> Open a notepad as administrator, from file ---Open--- navigate here-->C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, open host)
scroll down the page, and make sure the local host is having this IP ---> 127.0.0.1 in front of it

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure a program isn't using port 80 - If you have skype or related programs running, check them. Maybe boot into windows in safe mode and try running WAMP - if it works you know something is using port 80.